# In the lower central series of a group $G$, how to show each of the subgroups is fully invariant?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If we have that $$G = \gamma_1(G) \ge \gamma_2(G) \ge \cdots,$$ is a LSC and $\gamma_{i+1}(G)=[\gamma_{i}(G),G]$.

I can see that for every endomorphism of $G$, it is true that $f([x,g])\in [G,G]$, where $[x,g] \in [\gamma_i(G),G]$, but I can't see how to show $f([x,g]) \in [\gamma_i(G),G]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

(1) For any $\;i\;$ , $\;\gamma_i(G)\lhd G\;$, and a subgroup $\;N\le G\;$ is normal iff $\;[N,G]\le N\;$ .

(2) Induction, with $\;\gamma_i(G)=[G,G]\;$  fully invariant being (almost...or without almost) trivial.

Comment: Thank you. Now using induction, assuming the result true for $i=k$, If $[x,g] \in \gamma_{k+1}(G)$, then because $f(\gamma_{k+1}(G)) \le f(\gamma_k(G))$, it follows that $f([x,g]) = [f(x),f(g)] \in [f(\gamma_k(G),G] \le [\gamma_k(G),G] = \gamma_{k+1}(G)$. Is this correct?

Comment: @J.Doe That looks correct.